# Como dividir uma coluna em duas usando um separador que não é caractere?

Tags: r, regex

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Suponha o seguinte dataset:

```
df <- tibble(reference = c("Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)","Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)",
                       "Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)USDA-ARS (2016)",
                       "Govaerts (2016)USDA-ARS (2016)","Holm et al. (1979)Govaerts (2016)EPPO (2021)",
                       "USDA-ARS (2016)",
                       "Cook and Luond (1982)USDA-ARS (2016)EPPO (2021)","Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)USDA-ARS (2016)",
                       "USDA-ARS (2016)Cook and Luond (1982)"))



> df
# A tibble: 9 x 1
  reference                                      
  <chr>                                          
1 Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)                 
2 Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)                 
3 Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)USDA-ARS (2016)  
4 Govaerts (2016)USDA-ARS (2016)                 
5 Holm et al. (1979)Govaerts (2016)EPPO (2021)   
6 USDA-ARS (2016)                                
7 Cook and Luond (1982)USDA-ARS (2016)EPPO (2021)
8 Govaerts (2016)Pieterse (1981)USDA-ARS (2016)  
9 USDA-ARS (2016)Cook and Luond (1982)
```

A ideia é separar as linhas usando como separador "algo que não é um caractere" (na verdade não sei nem como denominar) que é o "elemento" (na falta de um termo melhor) **ENTRE** o "fecha parênteses" e a "primeira letra maíscula" do nome que vem em seguida.
Como não há nenhum caractere entre estes dois elementos, fico confuso sobre como proceder.

Imaginei que se não especificasse nada depois do "precedido por um fecha parênteses" `(?<=\\))` eu conseguiria essa quebra:

```
separate_rows(df, reference, sep = "(?<=\\))")
```

No entanto, o que obtive foi:

```
> separate_rows(df, reference, sep = "(?<=\\))")
# A tibble: 30 x 1
   reference        
   <chr>            
 1 "Govaerts (2016)"
 2 "Pieterse (1981)"
 3 ""               
 4 "Govaerts (2016)"
 5 "Pieterse (1981)"
 6 ""               
 7 "Govaerts (2016)"
 8 "Pieterse (1981)"
 9 "USDA-ARS (2016)"
10 ""               
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Até consegui remover as linhas `""` usando `filter()`:

```
separate_rows(df, reference, sep = "(?<=\\))") %>% 
  filter(reference!= "")

# A tibble: 21 x 1
   reference         
   <chr>             
 1 Govaerts (2016)   
 2 Pieterse (1981)   
 3 Govaerts (2016)   
 4 Pieterse (1981)   
 5 Govaerts (2016)   
 6 Pieterse (1981)   
 7 USDA-ARS (2016)   
 8 Govaerts (2016)   
 9 USDA-ARS (2016)   
10 Holm et al. (1979)
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Também tentei algo com o `str_replace_all()`.

```
  
df %>% 
  mutate(reference = str_replace_all(reference, 
                                     pattern = "(\\))([A-Z])",
                                     replacement = "\\1XXX\\2")) %>% 
  separate_rows(reference, sep = "XXX")
```

O resultado é conforme o pretendido, embora tenha achado essa abordagem mais prolixa.

```
# A tibble: 21 x 1
   reference         
   <chr>             
 1 Govaerts (2016)   
 2 Pieterse (1981)   
 3 Govaerts (2016)   
 4 Pieterse (1981)   
 5 Govaerts (2016)   
 6 Pieterse (1981)   
 7 USDA-ARS (2016)   
 8 Govaerts (2016)   
 9 USDA-ARS (2016)   
10 Holm et al. (1979)
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Em suma, meu objetivo mesmo é saber como se especifica "algo que não é um caractere" entre dois caracteres.

Comment: "algo que não é um caractere entre dois caracteres", considerado que `caractere` seja alfanumérico = `/([^\w\d\s\n.-])(?!\w\d)/gm`

Comment: @CypherPotato O atalho `\w` já inclui dígitos, então usar junto com `\d` na mesma classe de caracteres é redundante (ou seja, a primeira parte poderia ser apenas `[^\w\s\n.-]`). Mas na verdade o problema não é esse, a questão é quebrar a string entre o `)` e a letra maiúscula seguinte, portanto o "*algo que não é um caractere entre dois caracteres*" é simplesmente a **posição** entre o `)` e a letra (ver resposta abaixo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
separate_rows(df, reference, sep = "(?<=\\))(?=[A-Z])")
```

O que você chama de "*algo que não é um caractere*" é na verdade um "[*zero-length match*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)" (*matches* de tamanho zero) ou "*zero-length assertion*", que são expressões que não correspondem a um caractere, e sim a uma **posição** da string.

No caso, temos dois [*lookarounds*](https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?<=\\))` é um *lookbehind*, que corresponde a uma posição da string que possui um `)` antes, e `(?=[A-Z])` é um *lookahead*, que corresponde a uma posição da string que possui uma letra maiúscula depois.

Ambos só verificam se algo existe antes ou depois, mas não correspondem a nenhum caractere. Eles só indicam a posição que possui tais caracteres antes ou depois.

Ou seja, a expressão pega todas as posições da string que possuem um `)` antes e uma letra maiúscula depois. Com isso ele faz as quebras nos lugares que deseja, e o resultado é:

```
 1 Govaerts (2016)   
 2 Pieterse (1981)   
 3 Govaerts (2016)   
 4 Pieterse (1981)   
 5 Govaerts (2016)   
 6 Pieterse (1981)   
 7 USDA-ARS (2016)   
 8 Govaerts (2016)   
 9 USDA-ARS (2016)   
10 Holm et al. (1979)
# ... with 11 more rows
```

---

No seu caso não funcionou porque ao usar somente `(?<=\\))`, você está dizendo para fazer a quebra nas posições que possuem um `)` antes. E o final da string é uma dessas posições, já que elas terminam com `)` (e como não tem nada depois, a quebra acaba gerando uma string vazia - é um comportamento comum em várias linguagens, quando o separador está no início ou fim da string).

Adicionando `(?=[A-Z])`, você deixa claro que a quebra só deve ser feita se além do `)` antes, também tiver uma letra maiúscula depois, assim ele ignora os `)` que estão no final da string.

---

Por fim, vale lembrar que `[A-Z]` não considera letras acentuadas. Então se quiser, pode trocar para alguma dessas alternativas:

```
separate_rows(df, reference, sep = "(?<=\\))(?=\\p{Lu})")
separate_rows(df, reference, sep = "(?<=\\))(?=\\p{Latin})")
separate_rows(df, reference, sep = "(?<=\\))(?=[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÃÕÂÊÔÇÀ])")
```

A primeira opção (`\p{Lu}`) pega todas as letras maiúsculas definidas pelo Unicode, o que inclui letras de outros alfabetos, como o grego, cirílico, etc ([a lista é bem grande](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)).

Se não quiser ser tão abrangente, pode usar a segunda opção (`\p{Latin}`), que considera somente os caracteres do *Latin script* (considera menos caracteres que a primeira opção, mas ainda sim [não se resume ao nosso alfabeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode)).

Por fim, a terceira opção (`[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÃÕÂÊÔÇÀ]`) é uma lista fixa com as letras de "A" a "Z" sem acento, mais as letras acentuadas (basta adicionar ou remover os caracteres que deseja para que se adeque à sua necessidade).

Comment: Perfeito! Grato também pela apresentação do termo "*zero-length match*"